# How does the PROP array relate to the PROPS array in the Abaqus FORTRAN UMAT code?

Tags: arrays, fortran, abaqus

I have been going through the publicly available crystal plasticity FORTRAN [subroutine](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Ejk2079/Kysar_Research_Laboratory/Single_Crystal_UMAT.html), however, I couldn't understand how the input materials were being passed through the subroutines and functions.

So, in the main UMAT, the variable PROPS points towards the material constants entered in the *USER MATERIAL option in the input file. For the subroutine, this value is 125.

Now the subroutines being called by UMAT has defined another variable PROP, which takes different values like

In **line 1430**;

```
    C            PROP(1) - PROP(3) -- direction of the first vector in 
    C                       local cubic crystal system
```

While in **Line 2167**, (for i = 1)

```
C     PROP   -- material constants characterizing the self- and latent-
C               hardening law (INPUT)
C
C               For the HYPER SECANT hardening law 
C               PROP(1,i) -- initial hardening modulus H0 in the ith 
C                            set of slip systems
C               PROP(2,i) -- saturation stress TAUs in the ith set of  
C                            slip systems
C               PROP(3,i) -- initial critical resolved shear stress 
C                            TAU0 in the ith set of slip systems
```

While I couldn't find any relation between PROPS and PROP in the code, I could see that the appropriate material constants were being implemented by PROP.

I am not able to understand how PROP is able to get the property constants from the input file? Can someone explain how this works?

The fortran [code](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Ejk2079/fem/umatcrystal_mod.f).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ROTATION` subroutine is defined at L.1404 (comments removed for clarity):

```
SUBROUTINE ROTATION (PROP, ROTATE)
      IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
      DIMENSION PROP(16), ROTATE(3,3), TERM1(3,3), TERM2(3,3), INDX(3) 
      [...]
```

Fortran works on the principle of 'pass-by-reference', i.e. function arguments actually receive pointers to wherever the variable 'lives' in memory. Thus, the subroutine `ROTATION` interprets its first argument as the address of (the start of) a 16-element double-precision array, while the second argument is the address of a 3x3 double precision array.

At L.569 you see the function being called:

`CALL ROTATION (PROPS(57), ROTATE)`

Thus the address it is being *given* is that of the 57th element of `PROPS`. This means the subroutine effectively has access to the contents of `PROPS(57)`-`PROPS(72)`. According to the commentary at the start (L.385),

```
PROPS(57) - PROPS(72) -- parameters characterizing the initial 
C                                orientation of a single crystal in 
C                                global system
```

When the subroutine finishes, its result is in the array `ROTATE` it received at L.569.

Comment: Fortran doesn't work "on the principle of 'pass-by-reference'", but the concept here is called _sequence association_.  One can find many other questions and answers here using that search term.

Comment: @francescalus "In general, Fortran routines pass arguments by reference." https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5262/auto42/index.html

Comment: That may be true for that particular implementation. The standard does not require it. Other methods can be, and are, used.

Comment: "In general, passing by reference" is far from "working on the principle of passing by reference". There are many times where copies are preferred, and times where copies are all but required. Sequence association is the important concept here and how that effect is demonstrated is not so much.